# What is the meaning and substance of Imperial?

Tags: political-philosophy, marx, locke

In post-colonial and marxist theory one often comes across the word *Imperial*. What is the meaning of this word? How does it differ from say a monarchy? Are there in fact several kinds of Imperialism? Does classical political theory in the tradition of Locke use this word?

Comment: An empire typically spans several countries. 'Imperialism' has connotations relating to the way recent real-world empires behaved (so ideas of paternalism, exploitation, aggressive expansion and cultural superiority for a start).

Comment: A Imperialist could also be a synonym for a Naturalist.

Comment: @Meyer: in what way?

Comment: @NeilMeyer Yea that definitely merits some explanation. Very confusing.

Comment: My bad confusing Imperialist with Empiricist.

Comment: There's a [great post](http://criticallegalthinking.com/2013/06/19/imperium-notes-on-the-thought-of-spinoza/) at *Critical Legal Thinking* about imperium from Spinoza's perspective; they propose: "An imper­ium is a sin­gu­lar­ity of pro­jec­tion which does not appear in the field of right as an ori­gin prior to that projection." --Might be worth a look! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only give a brief overview for the Marxist definition of Imperialism as I don't know enough about the term as used in classical political theory. [The Wikipedia entry may be better suited for that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperialism).

The classical Marxist analysis of Imperialism (though I don't know if this was Lenin, or Luxembourg, or Marx himself) states that the development of capitalism within one nation state sooner or later reaches a limit. Capitalist systems want to grow and will always need more resources, workers or people buying the stuff.

At this point the state tries to secure overseas resources, markets or workforce for its capitalists. This can happen by subjugating and colonizing another part of the world or by forcing other countries to lower tariffs. This is usually called Imperialism.

Note: Imperialism is often simply used as a derogatory term for policies one does not like, or a state or certain policies are called 'Imperialist' in the same way, without bothering with the question of whether  the loose definition given above fits. Sometimes Imperialism is simply used as a synonym for the USA and its allies.

Comment: this answer could be expanded with links, or even better, a few sentences about the Negris and Hardts 'Empire' concept ... too lazy now.

Comment: Does this apply only to modern Empires say since the invention of nation states in Europe; How about Alexanders Empire, The Ottoman Empire or the Mughal Empire? Or even Genghis Khans?

Comment: this definition would only apply to basically modern, capitalist states.

Comment: Does this mean that the former Soviet Union is not considered an Empire?

Comment: Depends on who you ask! Even within the marxist framework, many consider the SU as a sort of state capitalism and an imperialist power. And from the pserpective of colonies or sattelite states, it may not make a big difference if the strict definition applies ...

Comment: I'd go along with that analysis.

Comment: Mozibur, originally it was an ideological construction made against existing multi-nation Empires. As an example, Lenin said that Russian Empire is a "Prison of Nations". In the XX century, most capitalist empires was decay, and SU remains Empire in the classical (not marxist) definition - i.e. multi-nation and joined by brute force. Now marxists says about "economical exploitation" - i.e. attempts of any country to get better conditions in the trade with another country, so the term becomes pretty blurry, that is again great for ideology goals

Answer (score 1):

Imperial literally means, the desire to create or maintain an empire. An empire is control or dominion over more than one's own land for the purpose of enriching oneself.. or one's own land. In this sense, any nation that uses force to obtain resources from a foreign land is engaging in imperialism. The most blatent modern example is the US. But The UK is possibly the words most notorious imperialist nation. The connotation when used as a pejorative is usually that imperialist nations are living beyond the means that could be supported were they not subjugating others.

Comment: First, as a formal note, answers that only state (potentially controversial) things as if they were facts without backing them up with sources are to be considered "mere opinion" here and are not good answers. Secondly, as a political note, even if it are political and economic means used, the most imperialist nation to date in your terms is probably China. And Russia is not really a minor player at that as well.

Comment: The appelation "imperialist" is a pejorative term used by internationalists to describe nationalists. To an internationalist.. imperialism is anti humanist. Rome and Britain ostensibly believed they were spreading 'civilisation'. Bringing the peace of civilization. The US talks about democracy. If this is contentious, it rather depends on your point of view.. but this is the correct answer to the question.